# models.UniqueConstraint doesn't raise an error when submitting the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am wondering why I am not getting an error when I submit a form where I've added a UniqueConstraint on two of the fields together; the data doesn't get submitted to the database (which is expected because of the constraint I've added to the model) and all that happens is that the same form is returned. I want some sort of indication under the Key Name field to say something like "Key Name already exists". Here is my code:

In **models.py**

```
 # The clean function gets called from is_valid() calls in views
def clean (self) :

    import logging

    log = logging.getLogger("app")

    log.debug("the clean function")

    regex = '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$'
    if re.search(regex, self.version) == None:
        raise ValidationError (
             {'version' : ['Version number is invalid. Use format major.minor']}
        ) 

class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Key Definition"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['key_name', 'developer_email'], name='unique key names for each user')
        ]
```

In **forms.py**

```
class KeyDefinitionForm (BSModalModelForm) :

       ## code I have not included goes here ##    

        def save(self):
        log.debug("ENTER: forms.KeyDefinitionForm.save")
        if self.request:
            instance = super(CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, self).save()
        log.debug("EXIT: forms.KeyDefinitionForm.save")
        return instance
```

In **views.py**

```
class KeyDefinitionView (BSModalCreateView) :

"""Class based view for key definition loading form."""
model = KeyDefinition
form_class = KeyDefinitionForm
template_name = 'generate_keys/keydef_add_modal.html'
body_template_name = 'generate_keys/keydef_add_body.html'

def get(self, request):
    log.debug("ENTER: views.KeyDefinitionView.get()")
    form = self.form_class(
        initial = {
            'developer_email' : request.user.email,
            'issue_date' : datetime.date.today(),
            'HGE_TLS' : 'N',
        }
    )
    data = {
        'form' : form,
    }
    result = render(request, self.template_name, data)
    log.debug("EXIT: views.KeyDefinitionView.get()")
    return result

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
    log.debug("ENTER: views.KeyDefinitionView.post()")
    result = super().post(request, args, kwargs)

    print(result)

    log.debug("EXIT: views.KeyDefinitionView.post()")
    return result
```

Comment: Do you want to display an error/error message on the front-end if form submission fails?

Comment: @UsamaSaeed yes I do. For example, when a field in Django is required I get the "This field is required" message under the empty box where I should have inputted a value. So I want something like this where it says "Key name already exists"

Comment: Ok, are you using the " django-bootstrap-modal-forms 2.2.0" library for this process because "BSModalCreateView" is not a generic class view of Django?

Comment: @UsamaSaeed yes i am

Comment: Have you added code for displaying django messages in your templates for the front-end or not?

Comment: There are 2 ways to display Django messages and errors response and I just want to make sure that you are using 1 of them before providing any solution.

Comment: @UsamaSaeed I haven't in my templates but I have added a clean() function in that model which checks the format of some input.. (i can add this into my question so you'll see what I mean). But in terms of the templates.. no...

Comment: Can you share your model code as well, so I can test this in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code to either your base template (if you are extending your base template for the template with your form) or in your form template. This code will show you any validation messages that Django's generic view sent with template rendering.

> You need to add this code at the top of other content in your template so it renders messages at top of your page content. This tag will load only when there is the message passed to the front-end with the HTTP request

Template.py

```
{% for message in messages %}
   <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
       {{ message }}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, add this code in your form for receiving form errors that are not related to any form field.

Template.py (Form template)

```
<form method='post'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.non_field_errors }}
   .
   .
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. What is "messages"? Do I need to define that somewhere? Also I have highlighted here something I found which has helped me do what I want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055971/unique-together-in-meta-vs-validate-unique-function-in-model

Comment: However, still not sure if it's the right way...

Comment: Messages are the way to give feedback to the user about processes they perform to keep them updated about their success or failure. Check the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/ to know about them in detail. Messages are part of all Django projects by default, so you don't have to add any functionality for them, you just need to import them into your views and pass the message whenever you want. You can get all the information you want in the documentation.

Comment: This raises an error message at the top of the form, which is not what I want. validate_unique raises a ValidationError on the field (i.e. displays the message at the bottom of the input box) which is what I want, but still not sure if it's the best way to do so.