# unique_together in Meta vs validate_unique function in model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to know the difference between these two methods of checking for unique-ness.

I have two fields which I do not want there to be duplicates of - key_name and developer_email - i.e. a developer can not have two keys with the same name. But two developers can have a key with the same name as each other.

I found out about unique_together so I added this to **KeyDefinitions** in **models.py:**

```
    class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Key Definition"
    #constraints = [
    #     models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['key_name', 'developer_email'], name='unique key names for each user')
    #]

    unique_together = [['key_name', 'developer_email']]
```

However, when I tested this by inputting a duplicate key_name and hitting "OK" on my form it just gives me back the form filled in and no errors. Although an entry hasn't been added to the database which tells me that this code is doing something.

I wanted an error to be raised so I found out about `validate_unique` and added it to the same model like so:

```
    def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    # I feel like this function makes constraints/unique_together option in Meta obsolete ?!
    qs = KeyDefinition.objects.filter(key_name=self.key_name, developer_email=self.developer_email) # need to filter by developer too
    print(qs)
    if qs:
        raise ValidationError (
             {'key_name' : ['This Key Name already exists']} 
        )
    return super().validate_unique(exclude)
```

The above code gave me what I wanted - i.e. an error message under the input field if a duplicate has been detected.

Now, my question is this - why use the constraints/unique_together options in the Meta class if we can just use the validate_unique function to make sure a duplicate isn't submitted? Is it because there's a chance someone could add an entry manually to the database? If so, why doesn't Django handle this instead of me overriding a function - I just don't know if this is the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: The best way is the unique_together as it is enforced at the database level, which means no one can add duplicate data directly into the database. The issue you are facing is that you are not using Django messages. Since you are using a generic create view they will return an error message if there is any validation error in the form or model. 

You should consider using Django messages as I told you earlier and see if results are according to your vision.

Comment: I use `unique_together = ['field_1', 'field_2']` within the model `class Meta:` in a number of situations and it works like a champ. The browser will give me an error as soon as I submit. Question - if you added `unique_together` to the model's `class Meta:` did you then run makemigrations and migrate on the DB? I know it's an obvious question, but if your model has that in place and it's not working that looks a lot like the DB hasn't been updated yet.